# RGBaster - Image from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: javascript, html, web, cross-domain, cors

So I'm trying to use the plugin RGBaster to pull an image and then get the primary color. I'm hosting the site on GoDaddy and wordpress is the backend.

I'm getting this error in the Chrome Console

> Image from origin 'http://i0.wp.com' has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://MYSITEHERE.COM' is therefore not allowed access.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? I can't find any info for images, I've found several links about cross origin but they all seem related to fonts.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @SLaks So how does that help me? Is there a configuration or something you know of I can use?

Comment: You need to configure your server to send that header.

Comment: @SLaks I'm new to this server-side CORS stuff. Is there a line of code that I should add to a certain file or something?

Answer (score 0):

You must probably set up CORS on the server. See this answer in this post: [localhost is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27354931/4324327)