# localhost is therefore not allowed access

Tags: php, ajax, cross-browser, cross-domain, cors

To solve CORS issue, I wrote there

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

in my server site

but during my development I'm seeing this error

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I thought allow-origin: * will solve everything? But why it says header contain multiple values?

Comment: Can you please refer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem when accidently enabling CORS twice. Check to make sure you did not enable it in apache, or that the header is not being set twice. As a sanity check you can try to remove the header and add it right back before you serve out your response.

Ex:

```
header_remove('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: @mike19911 K then my suspicions are correct. Do more than just copy paste that code :). It doesn't solve the problem, it just clearly identifies what needs to be fixed :).

Answer (score 1):

Due to browser security restrictions, most Ajax requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol. But Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

If you have n't used JSONP yet. The Wikipedia Says

> JSONP or “JSON with padding” is a complement to the base JSON data
>   format, a usage pattern that allows a page to request and more
>   meaningfully use JSON from a server other than the primary server.

So your ajax call should be like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        crossOrigin: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using * will not work. The below PHP code will accept all requests from all domains and works in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```
$origin=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']:$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);        
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1');
```

Accepting requests from all domains is insecure. For a better (but slightly more complex) solution, see here: [CORS That Works In IE, Firefox, Chrome And Safari](https://404it.no/en/blog/cors_that_works_in_ie_firefox_chrome_and_safari)